# How many relations on set {a,b,c} are reflexive and antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Question 1. I have seen the matrix way to solve this question, I am wondering how to use combinatorics in calculating the number of antisymmetric relations and then throw in reflexive tuples.

My idea as following, $3$ elements in a set which will generate $9$ tuples, $3$ of which are "reflexive tuples" and the rest will be in pairs as symmetric. 
$2^6$ is the total number of a reflexive relation, then minus not antisymmetric relations. {a,b,c} are obviously distinct, if both "symmetric pairs in the reflexive relation, then it's not antisymmetric" Then it turns out $2^6 -2^3 =56$. The answer should be $27$. I don't see what has gone wrong here.
*Please note that I didn't claim the complement of symmetric is antisymmetric, but under the constraint of reflexive relation it is.*

Question 2. Asking for further clarification, if symmetric and antisymmetric implies reflexive?

Question 3. If an empty set or any set with one tuple only could claim that it's antisymmetric?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is aa, bb, cc, ab, bc, cb symmetric or antisymmetric?

Comment: neither. I see.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer $a,b,c$ are distinct.

For the flaw in your reasoning see the comment of Brian.

Let us count the number of relations on $\{a,b,c\}$ that are reflexive and are not anti-symmetric.

We can write the set of relations as: $$\mathcal R(\{a,b\})\cup\mathcal R(\{a,c\})\cup \mathcal R(\{b,c\})$$where e.g. $R\in\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$ if and only if $R$ is reflexive relation on $\{a,b,c\}$ with $\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,a\rangle\in R$.

Applying inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:$$|\mathcal R(\{a,b\})\cup\mathcal R(\{a,c\})\cup \mathcal R(\{b,c\})|=$$$$3|\mathcal R(\{a,b\})|-3|\mathcal R(\{a,b\})\cap\mathcal R(\{a,c\})|+|\mathcal R(\{a,b\})\cap\mathcal R(\{a,c\})\cap \mathcal R(\{b,c\})|=$$$$3\cdot2^4-3\cdot2^2+1=37$$
So the number of relations on $\{a,b,c\}$ that are reflexive and anti-symmetric equals:$$2^6-37=64-37=27$$

question 2:

The empty relation on any set is symmetric and anti-symmetric but is only reflexive if it is looked at as a relation on the empty set.

question 3: (I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly)

If a set is empty then there is only one relation on that set, which is the empty relation. The empty relation is anti-symmetric (as said above).

If a set is a singleton $\{a\}$ then there are two relations on it: the empty relation and the relation $\{\langle a,a\rangle\}$. Both are anti-symmetric.

Comment: Really appreciate that. I think there is a typo in question 1. $R\in\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$ in question seems to be the power set of the cartesian product of set {a,b}. Then any $ R\in\mathcal R(\{a,b\}) $ won't be reflexive on {a,b,c}. I know how do you get $37$, but I am not sure what kind of set that 37 stands for. Would you please further enlighten me.

Comment: I don't see any typo. Why do you think that $R\in\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$ denotes the powerset of the cartesian product of set $\{a,b\}$? Every $R\in\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$ is a subset of $\{a,b,c\}^2$ that contains the $5$ elements $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,a)$ and eventually more. There are other $4$ candidates (which are $(a,c),(c,a),(b,c),(c,b)$) leading to cardinality $2^4$ for $\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$.

Comment: In the answer it is proved that exactly $37$ of  the $64$ reflexive relations on $\{a,b,c\}$ are not anti-symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I meant  $\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$ denotes the power set of the cartesian product of  {a,b}. Now I see. $\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$ is the collection of relations that at least contains $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,a)$. Each relation in that whole union could be symmetric or not symmetric.

Comment: $\mathcal R(\{a,b\})$ indeed has elements (i.e. relations on $\{a,b,c\}$) that are symmetric (e.g. $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,a)\}$) and also has elements that are not symmetric  (e.g. $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,a),(a,c)\}$). This shows that a relation that is not antisymmetric can be symmetric but also can be not symmetric. If there are still things unclear, then please let me know.

Comment: one more question, if the question asks how many relations are symmetric and antisymmetric, is that just gonna be $2^3$? Just the power set of the number of  reflexive tuples

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A relation $R$ is symmetric over set $S$ when $\forall x\in S~.(x,x)\in R$.

The relation is antisymmetric when $\forall x\in S~\forall y\in S~.((x,y)\in R\wedge (y,x)\in R\to x=y)$

So for any $x>y$ either $[(x,y)\in R\wedge(y,x)\notin R]$, $[(x,y)\notin R\wedge(y,x)\in R]$, or $[(x,y)\notin R\wedge(y,x)\notin R]$ will be the case.  That is for every pair $(x,y)$ where $x>y$ there will be three choices (include the pair, include its inverse, or include neither).

So the count of relations over $\{a,b,c\}$ which will be reflexive and antisymmetric will be the count of ways to make *three* independent choices with *three* options.

---

> Question 2. Asking for further clarification, if symmetric and antisymmetric implies reflexive?

No.  Neither of symmetry nor antisymmetry alone implies reflexivity.  Together they both imply that *if* any elements are related, then they will be the same element; that is not the same thing as reflexivity.  $$\forall x\in S~\forall y\in S~.((x,y)\in R\to x=y)$$

> Question 3. If an empty set or any set with one tuple only could claim that it's antisymmetric?

A relation is *not* antisymmetric if there exists any pair of non-identical members *and* its inverse that are both in the relation.  $$\exists x\in S~\exists y\in S~.(x\neq y\wedge (x,y)\in R\wedge(y,x)\in R)$$

So if there exists none such, the relation is antisymmetric.

Comment: really appreciate that!!!